# How to tab left in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, tabs

In most editors when you click Shift+Tab the selected text moves 4 spaces to the left. This doesn't work for me in Pycharm. I'm in Windows 10 and using Pycharm 2021.3.3 Professional Edition.

What I have:

```
    def my_function():
        my_code
        return my_result
```

What I want:

```
def my_function():
    my_code
    return my_result
```

What's the correct shortcut to get this done and how can I configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in that Shift+Tab "tabs backwards". In the PyCharm IDE the language that is used for this is *Unindent Line or Selection*. My advice is to open your PyCharm **Preferences** from the file menu and then clicking on the **Keymap** category on the left side of the newly opened window. View the **Editor Actions** by dropping down its contents.

These are all Editor Shortcuts to be used in your IDE. Here you will find *Unindent Line or Selection* with the current shortcut that is used displayed to its right. Double click to remove its current setting. Double click it again and click "Add _____ Shortcut" to reassign it to your desire.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine. In my Pycharm version is File/Settings at the start, the rest is exaclty like you said.

Comment: In mac its Shift + tab